# How to handle Facebook, Google, Twitter login / registration on database?

Tags: authentication, oauth, backend, registration

Currently my application only supports email & password login and I would like to implement support for google and Facebook.

Problem here is that I'm not sure how I should handle the registration / login process.

Ideas for the process:
When the user starts the registration process user authenticates to google, I get the needed data from Google (name, age, email) and after retrieving the data I will add them into database.

Next time when user logins with Google sign-in how do I identify if the user already exists in database?

Should I add a provider_Id property column into my database?

So the user table would look like: user_id, provider_Id, name, age, gender.

user_id is the I'd which is generated by me (1, 2, 3 etc) and the provider_id would be the uuid which is the Google user uuid.

Now when user logins with Google I could check if the given uuid matches the uuid in the database?

Those who have implemented similar registration / login could you share some process flows and what kind of data models you have.

Thanks in advance!